# No such user ERROR sssd

Tags: server, domain-server, sssd

Am joining the ubuntu machine to our active directory server when i type the command id  username@domain it is showing me the no such user error.
I have checked the sssd.config file and change the value.
use_fully_qualified_names = True to true but still it's not working.

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: You've not provided basic Ubuntu product/release details?  Are we to guess?